# CSS3 gradient background not working properly

Tags: css

I'm using CSS3 gradient, in local system its loading properly. once we uploaded that file its showing like stripe blocks with gradient.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/85sce/)**

**CSS:**

```
body {
    zoom: 1;
    opacity: 1;
     display:block;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-size: 100% /*Cover */;
    background: #e5dada;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e5dada 0%, #ffffff 99%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #e5dada), color-stop(99%, #ffffff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5dada 0%, #ffffff 99%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5dada 0%, #ffffff 99%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e5dada 0%, #ffffff 99%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e5dada 0%, #ffffff 99%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5dada', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0 );
}
```

I tried background-size:contain / cover / 100%.. nothing worked

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/r5wF5/)**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.gradient {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #e5dada;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);

  /* Fallback (could use .jpg/.png alternatively) */
  background-color: red;

  /* SVG fallback for IE 9 (could be data URI, or could use filter) */
  background-image: url(fallback-gradient.svg); 

  /* Safari 4, Chrome 1-9, iOS 3.2-4.3, Android 2.1-3.0 */
  background-image:
    -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(#e5dada), to(#fff));

  /* Safari 5.1, iOS 5.0-6.1, Chrome 10-25, Android 4.0-4.3 */
  background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5dada 0%, #fff 99%);

  /* Firefox 3.6 - 15 */
  background-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e5dada 0%, #fff 99%);

  /* Opera 11.1 - 12 */
  background-image:
    -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5dada 0%, #fff 99%);

  /* Opera 15+, Chrome 25+, IE 10+, Firefox 16+, Safari 6.1+, iOS 7+, Android 4.4+ */
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #e5dada 0%, #fff 99%);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

to your css.

Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/85sce/5/) here.

Answer (score 2):

The `background` property depends on the `height` of the element. You didn't set height of your empty `body` therefore it results in those repeated tiny strips. The `min-height` property of `body` tag wouldn't work unless you set `height: 100%` of the parent tag i.e. `html`.

[**Working Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/umayr/RuF32/)